# Makefile cannot able to target dependecies

Tags: makefile

```
#
# Makefile
#

# compiler to use
CXX = clang++

# flags to pass compiler
CXXFLAGS = -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors

# flags for the C PreProcessor
CPPFLAGS =  -MMD

# The maintainer's variant of CXXFLAGS
AM_CXXFLAGS =

# The command used to actually compile a C++ source file.
# The file name is appended to form the complete command line.
CXXCOMPILE =

# The command used to actually link a C++ program
CXXLINK =

# space-separated list of header files
HDRS =

# space-separated list of libraries, if any,
# each of which should be prefixed with -l
LIBS =  -lm -lpthread


# default target
# require that an argument be provided at the command line
# for the target name
TARGET = $(target)

> problem with this line
> It is just targeting the single .cpp
> But when I want make project folder 
#
# Makefile
#

# compiler to use
CXX = clang++

# flags to pass compiler
CXXFLAGS = -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors

# flags for the C PreProcessor
CPPFLAGS =  -MMD

# The maintainer's variant of CXXFLAGS
AM_CXXFLAGS =

# The command used to actually compile a C++ source file.
# The file name is appended to form the complete command line.
CXXCOMPILE =

# The command used to actually link a C++ program
CXXLINK =

# space-separated list of header files
HDRS =

# space-separated list of libraries, if any,
# each of which should be prefixed with -l
LIBS =  -lm -lpthread


# default target
# require that an argument be provided at the command line
# for the target name
TARGET = $(target)
```

> I cannot able to target header file and corresponding .cpp dependencies
>       all: $(TARGET)
>       **$(TARGET): $(TARGET).cpp ; $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXCOMPILE) $(CXXLINK) $(HDRS)  -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).cpp $(LIBS**)

```
# housekeeping
clean:
    rm -f core
```

Comment: What command did you use to run the `Makefile` ?

Comment: For single .cpp program it works fine...but when I create project folder where are header and .cpp file are dependent...it does not works... What argument should I pass in the command line or I have to change in this make file....

Comment: /tmp/blink_main-5b9ddd.o: In function `main':
/home/jharvard/Dropbox/FUNProgramming/funky/cppHub/Arduino_LED/blink_main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `Led::Led(int)'
/home/jharvard/Dropbox/FUNProgramming/funky/cppHub/Arduino_LED/blink_main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `Led::blinkLed(int)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [blink_main] Error 1

Comment: Linker failed with exit code 1

Comment: make blink    where blink.cpp is the targeting .cpp file